# IE 7 jquery bind and $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have treeview script and part of it looks like :

```
root.find("." + classControl).each(function () {
    $(this).bind('click', function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "-") {
            $(this).text("+");
        }
        else {
            $(this).text("-");
        }
        $(this).parentsUntil("li").parent().children("ul").toggle();
    });
});
```

It should find all collapse/show buttons and bind them proper function. It works in FF,Chrome,IE 8 but not in IE7 not. When I click on the button, it changes from + to - or the reverse, but it also sets all other buttons to empty text.

I think the problem must be with the this selector, because if I bind only simple alert(), it works even in IE7

Comment: Have you considered using $this.on instead of $this.bind. Here is a breakdown on the differences: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html.  This probably won't help though if your selectors are still out of wack.

Comment: Here's a small optimization of your current code, though I don't see anything that would cause the IE7 issue you are seeing. http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Q7p/1/ It uses event delegation too since all of your controls have a common root.

Comment: @KevinB: Impressive optimization there.

Comment: thank you, the IE is weird, because when the buttons dissapear and I resize window, they appear again. I don't get it

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?  It's possible that it's actually a css issue instead of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You want to force IE7 to repaint your objects - which it does if you resize the screen. There are various ways to do that, but here's one that is claimed to be working in a very similar situation to yours: [When does IE7 recompute styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458579/when-does-ie7-recompute-styles-doesnt-work-reliably-when-a-class-is-added-to-t)